# How to check if jQuery .each() is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to check if jQuery .each() function cant find something, then change txt value to 'default'.

```
$(this).closest('.filter-select__dropdown-inner').find('> .button--checkbox.button--active').each(function(i) {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (i == 0) {
        txt = val;
    } else {
        txt = txt + ', ' + val;
    }
});
```

im already try

```
if (i == null) {
    txt = 'default';
}
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: `i.length === 0` it doesnt work

Comment: @PutraFajarHasanuddin, it might be a contextual issue. If you're trying to find the size of the array _in which_ you are iterating, you'd be much better off using: ``$(this).closest('.filter-select__dropdown-inner').find('> .button--checkbox.button--active').length``. Using ``i`` in the context you described, would return the length of the first argument, for the array item you're currently iterating over.

Comment: Hold on, if it is empty set the text to 'default'?  What text?

Comment: Well you can try something like this as well: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ku9fgLwx/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.length` in jquery to get the length

```
var lnt = $(this).closest('.filter-select__dropdown-inner').find('> .button--checkbox.button--active');
if(lnt.length > 0) {

lnt.each(function(i) {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (i == 0) {
        txt = val;
    } else {
        txt = txt + ', ' + val;
    }
});

}
```

Comment: I edited the answer to make use of the variable to increase efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

make use of .length and check its empty or not.

```
var objcollection = $(this).closest('.filter-select__dropdown-inner').
         find('> .button--checkbox.button--active');

if(objcollection.length==0)
{
}
else
{
}
```